# Get Values from Checkboxes, Combine Each Div's Corresponding Data, and Change data-view

Tags: jquery, arrays, foreach

I have a bunch of divs with **data-state**, **data-county**, **data-city**, and **data-view**.

I also have three checkboxes whose values are **data-state**, **data-county**, and **data-city**. I want to be able to check them and depending on which ones are checked, combine each div's corresponding data into a new **data-view**.

I have for my button so far:

```
$("#change").click(function(){
  var checkedViews=[];
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
  checkedViews.push($(this).val());
  });
});
```

So that gets, for instance, **data-state**,**data-city**, and one of the divs should now have **data-view="connecticut_bridgeport"**. I've gotten started on a jsfiddle, but I just don't know where to go after getting the checked values.

https://jsfiddle.net/xbgu1sL6/

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you construct the checkedViews array you then loop through each div element with class 'info' and update the 'data-view' attribute based on the elements of the array. The way I did it is: I loop through each element of the list (which is a string of form "data-*") and I use this string as argument for jquery .attr() function. This means that the values of each attribute that was selected are appended to the 'view' string that I defined along with an underscore after each one and since the underscore is appended for each value, I have to eliminate the last one (i.e. the last character of the string). To do that I use the .slice() function.

Here's the code:

```
$("#change").click(function(){
    var checkedViews=[];
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
    checkedViews.push($(this).val());
    });

    $(".info").each(function () {   // for each div with class 'info'
        var info = $(this);
        var view = "";   // this will be the new value for data-view
        if (checkedViews.length == 0) view = "blank_";
        checkedViews.forEach(function (cv) {  
            view += info.attr(cv) + '_';   // append the value of selected attribute along with an underscore
        });
        view = view.slice(0, -1);   // remove last character
        $(this).attr("data-view", view);   // update data-view
    });
});
```

And you can see it on jsfiddle as well: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmw9xt8c/1)

Comment: A thing that I just noticed. If you press the button but no option is selected the value for data-view will be changed to "". I assume you still want it to be set to "blank". I edited the code to take that into account (added a line which checks if the array is empty).